# Typescript locale timezone issue with Date library

Tags: node.js, linux, typescript, timezone, window

TZ is an environment variable auto-set by node.
When calling `new Date();` in typescript, it's returning date in GMT+0000 although code is running on machine with Timezone GMT+0530.

Tried printing `console.log(process.env.TZ)` -> `"Asia/Calcutta"`
it's the correct Timezone, then what's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I realized, `console.log(process.env.TZ)` -> "Asia/Calcutta" is coming with extra double quotes.

Solution

```
const envTz = process.env.TZ
process.env.TZ = envTz?envTz:'Asia/Calcutta'.replaceAll('"', '');
```

This code can be mentioned at the very begining of the code / sserver code and it will be applied for that